# How to move add to cart at the last for each product in product list page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, list-view

> How to move add to cart at the last for each product in product list
>   page magento 2?

Comment: Make a layout file like this - app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: which theme you are using ?

Comment: @Pawan i am using custom theme parent theme is luma

Comment: @AdityaShah i want to move add to cart in list page at the end

Comment: in luma theme addto cart is already on last. I think there is some customisation in your custom theme.

Comment: @Pawan can't we change in list.phtml directly

Comment: Yes we can change, add you phtml code in OP.